# Combining two simple circuits into one

Tags: relay, ltspice

I want to combine two circuits into one circuit. Shown below are two simple circuits where the REL1 relay connects/breaks the circuit or provides power. I want to switch between "modes" using mosfets.

[image]

So, here is my idea. I want use two mosfet's (SW1 and SW2) and one SSR (Solid State Relay) for  full isolation.

[image]

Also I try simulate circuit in LTSpice:

[image]

I'm not sure if setting MCU_GPIO_3 to FLASE will ensure complete disconnection of the battery (MAIN_BAT). Can I ask for some guidance?

Comment: I say to watch out for the body diodes in the MOSFETs.  If someone connects the battery backwards then you'll short out the battery through those two diodes.  You can try it in your simulation to see what I mean.

Comment: @SteKulov, right. I can add diode and fuse but I considering replace battery and connecting power from DC/DC converter.